# ng-repeat sort complex objects having arrays inside it

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a structure like this which needs to be sorted by  Locations.Address.distance

```
{
    "Id": "123",
    "Type": "someType",          
    "Locations": [{
        "Address": {
            "Line1": "111 test dr",
            "City": "pope",
            "State": "AZ",
            "PostalCode": {
                "Part1": "87212"
            } 
        },
         "Distance": "0.7" }]  
},

{
    "Id": "456",
    "Type": "someType",          
    "Locations": [{
        "Address": {
            "Line1": "777 test dr",
            "City": "pope",
            "State": "AZ",
            "PostalCode": {
                "Part1": "87212"
            } 
        },
         "Distance": "0.1" }]  
}
```

Locations array will always have only 1 item. I want to sort such that the second object with id= 456 shows up as the first element, as it has distance = 0.1, which is lesser than that of the first element where distance = 0.7 . I tried something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
 sortedList =filter('orderBy')($scope.responseArray,'Locations.this[0].Distance'], false);
```

Comment: You'll have to use your own function. You can write your own custom angularjs filter fairly easily. [Here's a pretty good tutorial](https://www.guru99.com/angularjs-custom-filter.html) for learning how to do so

Comment: Although, if you are not needing the filter in your template, and you are only sorting programmatically in your controller, an angularjs solution is not necessary. JavaScript has a built-in [`.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function, into which you can pass a function defining your sort logic.

Comment: You can use sort() function. Please check my answer

Comment: Updated my answer with both $filter and sort approach with an working sample

Answer (score 1):

By using filter you do like below

```
 var result=$filter('orderBy')(this.items, 'Locations[0].Distance')
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-sort-complex-array?file=index.js

Another approach is to use javascript **sort()** method , which you can written your own logic to sort

```
var result = items.sort(function (a, b) {
  var distance1 = parseFloat(a.Locations[0].Distance); 
  var distance2 = parseFloat(b.Locations[0].Distance); 
  if (distance1 < distance2) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (distance1 > distance2) {
    return 1;
  }


  return 0;
});
```

Working demo

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularjs-complex-filter?file=home/home.controller.js

Answer (score 0):

The trick was to refer to the first item inside of Locations array without using "this":

```
 sortedList = $filter('orderBy')($scope.pharmacyResponse, Name.LastName','Locations[0].Distance'], false);
```